# iOS 10: Apple transport security "exception domains" no longer working

Tags: security, ios10, beta

I'm using iOS 10 beta 8, Xcode 8 beta 6.

Regarding Apple Transport Security (ATS) I'm finding that using "exception domains" isn't working in iOS10, but "allow arbitrary loads does". Anyone else confirm?

[image: ATS exception]

(I've removed the domain name from the image; this is an enterprise application and won't be affected by the app store ignoring ATS exceptions)

Answer (score 10):

Exception domains method works on me. 
Xcode 8.21, mac os 10.12.3 and react-native 0.42.3.

After modify the plist in xcode or text-editor mode as follows, you should close the terminal and simulator and restart it.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>example1.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>example2.org</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 3):

This might not be your problem but it solved mine.

The domain you type has to be the domain that will typically display in a browser i.e. if in your code you use `http://www.example.com` you should use `www.example.com` instead.
or
`http://example.com` should instead be `example.com` in plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <!-- Replace example.com with www.example.com if that is what you registered on your hosting service-->
    <key>example.com</key>
    <!-- instead of http://example.com -->
    <dict>
      <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use NSAllowsArbitraryLoads in App transportation Security.
I was having same issue but now it is resolved.[image]

Comment: This solution can be used only temporarily because it's insecure and thus not recommended by Apple.

Answer (score 2):

### 2021 example working fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
            <dict>
                <key>abcdef.com</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                    <true/>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Recall for Swift non-storyboard apps, there is by default no Info.plist file.

1. go to Target **(not project)**, Info
2. add any key (even a nonsensical one)
3. that will generate a conventional Info.plist file

Now you can modify the source of the Info.plist file as usual in the simple way.